# Url of Home.aspx page automatically convert to Default.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am developing a web application `webform` project. I have few web forms in it. I have some `anchor` elements that are performing redirection of pages. First let me show you the structure of my project:

[image]

I am trying to navigate to Customer/Home.aspx page from Login.aspx Page.
The issue I get is it automatically converts Home.aspx to Default.aspx. Here is how it resolves the Url:

[image]

And here is the html I am using:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="Customer/Home.aspx">Customer</a></li>
    <li><a href="Products/Home.aspx">Products</a></li>
    <li><a href="Customer/SalesOrder.aspx">Sales Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="About/About.aspx">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

How should I resolve these urls correctly?

**UPDATE**
I already have tried to use the LinkButton control but the Issue remains the same:

```
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnk" PostBackUrl="~/Customer/Home.aspx" runat="server">Customer</asp:LinkButton>
</li>
```

Comment: Elaborate on "navigating", are you clicking a link? Or `Response.Redirect`? Or? Are you logged in? What authentication are you using?

Comment: I am just clicking the anchor element.

Comment: Is the correct URL in the rendered HTML? Or does it change in the browser after clicking?

Comment: Might be worth learning a tool such as Fiddler so you can observe the requests/responses and see what changes when.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, Thanks @mxmissile for the closest hint regarding the issue. It was a redirect call in the code that went unseen.

Answer (score -1):

based on my experience I'm providing you with the following solutions.

1. The solution can sometimes be simple. Just try the clear the browser catch files.
2. Right click on the start up web form (in your case guess it's 'Login.aspx') and click 'Set as start Page' before compiling.
3. Try to place '../' before the url like (../Customer/Home.aspx). But this cannot be the issue unless you're trying to redirect from inside a directory.

Please do reply me if this didn't solve your problem and check the URL on the HTML source code of your page, try to attach a screenshot if possible.

Comment: Prove it then @mxmissile. Capture and send me screenshot with the same above texts if u can